# Does Window-target meta tag work for busting frames?

Tags: html, html-frames

Does adding the followin tag in the header section of a html document prevent the loading of the document within a frame? If so, why does anybody bother with Javascript methods?

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Window-target" CONTENT="_top" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that browsers don't support `<META HTTP-EQUIV="Window-target" CONTENT="_top" />` meta tag anymore, they simply ignore it. So that's why people bother with using JavaScript, as Gumbo suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Better use the [`BASE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE) instead:

```
<base target="_top">
```

But that does not prevent the document to be loaded inside a frame. It only will force all links to use the target `_top` as default target if not otherwise specified.

But if you want to prevent the document to be loaded inside a frame, try this JavaScript code:

```
if (top != self) {
    top.location.href = self.location.href;
}
```

Comment: So if I understand you correctly,the window-target doesn't apply to the current page, but is applied to the link within the current page. Is that correct?

Comment: @Aheho: To be honest, I’ve never heard of such an HTTP equivalent header field.